# IE11 clipping text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

On IE11 only, text clips on certain pages, the text is contained within a `<section>` with CSS like so.  Note that this works in IE10 and below, Chrome and FF, it is only IE11 that has this issue.

```
#rightpanel section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}
```

[image]

If you look at this photo, the text should run right to the edge of the blue box.  Note that this highlighting is applied with the IE11 DOM highlighter.

Comment: Can we have see a link to the page, or can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle? You haven't given us enough to go on here, really.

Comment: @OllyHodgson very true, unfortunately I cannot replicate it in a fiddle.  It happens twice on my webpage (its local not online) but I cannot replicate it in a fiddle!

Comment: This is often caused by a syntax error in CSS. For example see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162668/ie-11-clipping-text/24162834
See if you have something like this anywhere else in your CSS.

Comment: @Ynhockey You're answer is right, please write it here so I can mark it as correct

Comment: @Chris Done, posted as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often caused by a syntax error in CSS. For example see here:
[IE 11 clipping text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162668/ie-11-clipping-text/24162834)

See if you have something like this anywhere else in your CSS.