# IE 11 clipping text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have the same issue on my page as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116592/ie11-clipping-text).

Only difference: my page is online.  It's a simple page with a paragraph and divs, but still the text in the paragraph is clipped (independent on the location on the page).

I tried:

- giving it width,
- adding height,
- putting the paragraph in a separate div,
- creating a table,
- relocating to bottom.

All resulted in the same cut off text... Its online you can see it [here](http://www.visualcomponents.com/Insights/Cases):

Works in all other browsers but IE11... Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be in `screen.css` on line 913:

```
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;
```

If you cancel this line (I tried in the debugger), it works.

This is because you gave 3 pixel properties, which didn't seem to work in your example. Try changing it to two properties, for example:

```
text-shadow: 0px 1px #fff;
```

This should work as well.

Comment: According to w3 http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp there should only be 3 pixel properties (v shadow, h shadow, blur)

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am modifying my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be be related to the `text-shadow`  generically applied to `#content-wrapper`.

If you reset this on the paragraph the text re-appears.